# Azure resource for long running process in python

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, long-running-processes

I am trying to figure out the best way to run a python process typically taking 10-30 (max an hour ish) minutes on my local machine. The process will be manually triggered, and may not be triggered for ours or days.

I am a bit confused, because I read official ms-docs stating that one should avoid long running processes in function apps (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/performance-reliability#avoid-long-running-functions) but at the same time, the functionTimeout for the Premium and Dedicated plans can be unlimited.

I am hesitant to use a standard web app with an API since it seems overkill to have it running 24/7.

Are there any ideal resources for this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use consumption based [Azure durable functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=python), they can run for hours or even days.

Comment: How would one use durable functions to run a python sampling process, or for loop for that matter. I dont see how this can be decompled into smaller operations distributable over multiple functions?
Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: you would use Fan out/in pattern to distribute operations over multiple identical functions [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=python#fan-in-out)
@bjornhartmann

Comment: but such a python process cant be decoupled into smaller subprocesses?